# How to convert sysvinit script to systemd on Manjaro

Tags: linux, systemd

First, please don't consider this post as a systemd review or critic, but only and simply as a request for help.

Since I've not been able to find a solution to this problem with the systemd documentation, I've this question not solved for almost a year and a half that never ever received any answer.

So, here is the context:

I've a program (/opt/myprog) that can be sarted as a deamon service at boot time.

When using previous Debian, LMDE, Mint or Ubuntu OSes, I used SysVinit with the following script (myprog.sh within the /etc/init.d folder):

```
MYPROG_PATH=/opt/myprog_64
NAME="myprog"
START="-d"
STOP="-k"
TEST=""
VERSION="-v"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
STARTMESG="\nStarting $NAME in deamon mode.\n"
UPMESG="\$NAME is running.\n"
DOWNMESG="\$NAME is not running!\n"
TESTMESG="\nStarting NAME in client mode.\nHit Ctrl+C (or close the terminal) to stop mprog.\n"
STATUS=`pidof $NAME` 

# Exit if myprog is not installed
[ -x "$MYPROG_PATH/$NAME" ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
    start)
        sleep 3
        echo $STARTMESG
        cd $MYPROG_PATH
        ./$NAME $START
    ;;
    stop)
        cd $MYPROG_PATH
        ./$NAME $STOP
    ;;
    status)
        if [ "$STATUS" > 0 ] ; then
            echo $UPMESG
        else
            echo $DOWNMESG
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        cd $MYPROG_PATH
        ./$NAME $STOP
        echo $STARTMESG
        ./$NAME $START
    ;;
    version)
        cd $MYPROG_PATH
        ./$NAME $VERSION
    ;;
    test)
        cd $MYPROG_PATH
        echo $TESTMESG
        ./$NAME
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|status|restart|stop|version|test}" >&2
        exit 3
    ;;
esac
:
```

Now, since it's obvious that systemd will be widely adopted to replace SysVinit including with future Debian, Mint and Ubuntu distros as it's with CentOS, Fedroa or Ach and Manjaro, I've tried to adapt my sysVinit script to systemd with the following script that works but is too limited (myprog.service):

```
Description=myprog
ConditionFileExecutable=/opt/myprog_64
After=NetworkManager.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment="PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
ExecStart=/opt/myprog -d
ExecStop=/opt/myprog -k
ExecRestart=/opt/myprog-k : /opt/myprog -d
TimeoutSec=0
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, as systemd is advertised as compatible and more flexible than SysVinit, could anyone show me how to add the three following equivalent switches (status, test and version) that I have defined in the myprog.sh sysVinit script without responding with the classic and inelegant answer: "man is your friend" ?

```
/opt/myprog status to display the myprog status (i.e. running or not)    
/opt/myprog test to start myprog not as a deamon     
/opt/myprog version to display the release of myprog
```

Thank you in advance fo your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

`systemd` does not support custom implementation of arguments to `systemctl`.

So `systemctl status myprog` will show the results based the execution of `Exec*` settings.

`systemctl show myprog` uses the `Description` so you can use a version in your description if desired.

If you wan't to run your program not as a daemon, then you can start it outside of `systemd`.

Comment: Thank you danblack for the precisions I was "gessing". However, how anyone can then says systemd is "compatible" with SysVinit, and even more that systemd is "more flexible" than SysVinit. This is marketing lies and pure BS whatever the systemd gives.

Comment: Don't be too harsh. For the most part I've never seen a sysv init script run something the "test" not as a daemon (any for a service manager why would you?). For the most part the features you need are there. "more flexible" does seem an overreach, however the usual flexibility is accessible to sysadmin without a great understanding of systems programming.

Comment: Myprogram is actually in two parts. The first starts and watches the execution of the second and restarts it in case of problems. The reason for the "test" option is that when I run it as a daemon, I don't get its output in the terminal. So, starting myprogram with the test option skips the first part, starts the second part and then displays the possible messages that myprogram could display. Then, if necessary, I can correct some things. BTW, the sysvinit script runs  with all its options when systemd doesn't offer the so-called compatibility nor the falsely presented flexibility.